# My Django app fails after a while with sigterm on AWS Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: python, django, amazon-web-services

I have deployed a Django APP in AWS Elastic Beanstalk. Sometimes it works but after some requests it stops to work and reading the logs it returns:

```
 [Thu Feb 27 21:59:12.073643 2020] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 3195] AH00169: caught SIGTERM, 
 shutting down
 [Thu Feb 27 21:59:13.429395 2020] [suexec:notice] [pid 3568] AH01232: suEXEC mechanism enabled 
 (wrapper: /usr/sbin/suexec)
 [Thu Feb 27 21:59:13.495004 2020] [so:warn] [pid 3568] AH01574: module wsgi_module is already 
 loaded, skipping
[Thu Feb 27 21:59:13.534589 2020] [http2:warn] [pid 3568] AH10034: The mpm module (prefork.c) is 
not supported by mod_http2. The mpm determines how things are processed in your server. HTTP/2 has 
more demands in this regard and the currently selected mpm will just not do. This is an advisory 
warning. Your server will continue to work, but the HTTP/2 protocol will be inactive.
[Thu Feb 27 21:59:13.534607 2020] [http2:warn] [pid 3568] AH02951: mod_ssl does not seem to be 
enabled
[Thu Feb 27 21:59:13.535166 2020] [lbmethod_heartbeat:notice] [pid 3568] AH02282: No slotmem from 
mod_heartmonitor
[Thu Feb 27 21:59:13.535239 2020] [:warn] [pid 3568] mod_wsgi: Compiled for Python/3.6.2.
[Thu Feb 27 21:59:13.535252 2020] [:warn] [pid 3568] mod_wsgi: Runtime using Python/3.6.8.
[Thu Feb 27 21:59:13.539566 2020] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 3568] AH00163: Apache/2.4.41 (Amazon) 
mod_wsgi/3.5 Python/3.6.8 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Thu Feb 27 21:59:13.539582 2020] [core:notice] [pid 3568] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/httpd 
-D FOREGROUND'
```

May you help me in understanding which would be the problem?

Thank you

Comment: Sounds like your application (or Apache?) was asked to shut down. Are you aware of  any automation that might be stopping or replacing it? Do the various logs (your app, Apache, Elastic Beanstalk) indicate anything useful?

Comment: Hello jarmod, No I think no automation are included to stopping it.

Comment: The sigterm log could be normal Apache behavior, terminating workers.

Comment: @jarmod, the problem here is that the django app seems to have a normal behaviour but it become very slow and difficult to use, and when these problems occur the log also returns: Script timed out before returning headers: wsgi.py